# when using msbuild plugin in jenkins, words of console log are broken

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2012, jenkins, msbuild

In my office, I usually use jenkins to build my solution by msbuild automatically.
But jenkins's console log looks like this ����. logs are covered by strange characters.

I guess that it is maybe encoding problem between jenkins and msbuild.
To help your understanding, os is window server, my Jenkins ver. 1.517, my msbuild plugin ver. 1.21.
MSbuild ver. 4.0.30319.

if you want to ask any information, I'll answer that.

and my problem is not the result of solution. wheather success or fail, just I want to see the right characters not strange character.

this is my console log in my jenkins. I cut it.

```
Started by user anonymous
Building in workspace d:\10.jenkins\Home_8020\jobs\A\workspace
Path To MSBuild.exe: C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\msbuild.exe
Executing the command cmd.exe /C C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\msbuild.exe D:\10.Jenkins\Home_8020\jobs\A\workspace\build\win32\a.sln && exit %%ERRORLEVEL%% from d:\10.jenkins\Home_8020\jobs\A\workspace
[workspace] $ cmd.exe /C C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\msbuild.exe D:\10.Jenkins\Home_8020\jobs\A\workspace\build\win32\a.sln && exit %%ERRORLEVEL%%
Microsoft (R) Build Engine ���� 4.0.30319.18408
[Microsoft .NET Framework, ���� 4.0.30319.18444]
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

�� �ַ���� ������Ʈ�� �� �� �ϳ��� �����մϴ�. ���� ���带 ����Ϸ��� "/m" ����ġ�� �߰��Ͻʽÿ�.
���� ����: 2014-04-23 ���� 9:48:14
1 ����� "D:\10.Jenkins\Home_8020\jobs\CV_ADAS\workspace\build\win32\adas.sln" ������Ʈ(�⺻ ���)�Դϴ�.
ValidateSolutionConfiguration:
  �ַ�� ���� "Debug|Win32"��(��) �����ϰ� �ֽ��ϴ�.
"D:\10.Jenkins\Home_8020\jobs\A\workspace\build\win32\a.sln"(1) ������Ʈ�� 1 ��忡�� "D:\10.Jenkins\Home_8020\jobs\A\workspace\build\win32\a.vcxproj"(2)��(��) �����ϰ� �ֽ��ϴ�(�⺻ ���).
InitializeBuildStatus:
  "Debug\a.unsuccessfulbuild"�� ����(touching)�ϰ� �ֽ��ϴ�.
```

Answer (score 0):

What actual characters are you expecting to see in those places? What does the command line output look like, compared to Jenkins?

***Edit:***
It could be color formatting of `msbuild.exe` output.

The [**command line reference page**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164311.aspx) says you can use `/clp:disableconsolecolor` to disable colors. You need to add that to the command line arguments when triggering the build in Jenkins.

Or you can try installing **[AnsiColor plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/AnsiColor+Plugin)** on Jenkins which should be able to process color information and display that in the console log, but I haven't tried this on Windows (works like a charm on Linux though)

Comment: @JohnSaunders to something that looks right in OP's view. Without knowing what he is expecting to see, we can only guess what they are supposed to mean, but it is definitely an encoding issue

Comment: @Slav For example, Microsoft (R) Build Engine ���� 4.0.30319.18408
[Microsoft .NET Framework, ���� 4.0.30319.18444] in this part, original sentence is Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 4.0.30319.18408
[Microsoft .NET Framework, version 4.0.30319.18444]

Comment: So, it's replacing `version` with 4 rhombus question marks? In the command line, does `version` have any special formatting? Like a different color or extra tabs?

Comment: Updated answer based on the assumption that this is color information